# Write RegEx results from multiple html files to .txt outfile

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am having trouble writing the RegEx results I got from multiple html files (text not in English) to a .txt outfile. It prints them out as several strings on new lines onscreen, but when I try to write it to an outfile, it only writes one random string. My code looks like this: 
Could you please help how I could write all the strings to the outfile from all the approx 100 files?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import string
import re
import os

text = glob.glob('C:/Users/dell/Desktop/python-for-text-analysis-master/Notebooks/MEK/*')   
for filename in text:
    with open(filename, encoding='ISO-8859-1', errors="ignore") as f:
        mytext = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(mytext, "lxml")
extracted_text = soup.getText()

pattern = r"\ba\b\s\bleg[\w]+bb\b\s\b[\w]+\b"
result = (", ".join(re.findall(pattern, mytext)))

file = "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/python-for-text-analysis-master/Data/Charlie/charlie_neww.txt"
for row in result:
    with open (file, "w", encoding="iso-8859-1", errors="ignore") as outfile:
        print(result, end='\n', file=outfile)
```

Comment: I don't think you mean to `print(result)`...

Comment: Er, wait...`result` is a string.....what do you think `for row in result` is doing? Because I doubt it's doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `with open (file, "w", ...`

The "w" mode truncates the file (i.e. every time you open it, the file is cleared). Consider mode "a" for 'append'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to Python as it must be obvious...:) You saved my day. I really appreciate it!!